# How to properly sort an array using insertion sort?

Tags: c

I have whole program and it works but not properly. printArray function prints only first element of an Array and it doesn't seem to sort elements. 
I don't know how to deal with it.

```
int main(){
    int number;
    printf( "Give a number of elements:" );
    scanf("%d",&number);
    printf("Array to sort:");
    int* Array = createArray(number);
    int sizeArr = sizeof(Array)/sizeof(Array[0]);
    int *sortedArr = insertionSort(Array,sizeArr);
    puts("");
    printf("Sorted array by Insertion Sort:");
    printArr(sortedArr,sizeArr);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
int* createArray(int number){
    int *arr =(int*) malloc(sizeof(int*)*number);
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
        arr[i] = 1 + rand()%10;
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
    return arr;
}
int *insertionSort(int *arr,int sizeArr){
    int i, j,repArr;
    for(i=1;i<sizeArr;i++){
            repArr = arr[i];
            j=i-1;
    while(j>=0 && arr[j]>repArr){
        arr[j+1] = arr[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
        arr[j+1] = repArr;
    }
return arr;
}

void printArr(int*arr,int sizeArr){
    for(int i=0;i<sizeArr;i++){
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
        }
       puts("");
}
```

Comment: `malloc`... is it C?

Comment: @YSC: Seems like a mix - but the `cout<<endl;` ultimatively makes it C++ I guess... :-P

Comment: Please don't forget to show us a [Minimal, **Complete**, and **Verifiable** Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: [Here's a better insertion sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c)

Comment: I have changed i. Why am I not allowed to use malloc in C++? So, am I suppose to change all on C? :( I admit that I don't write in C++, but I want to learn so I hope that you will help ;)

Comment: `sizeof(Array)/sizeof(int)` is wrong. It should only be used on arrays, not on pointers.

Comment: but how replace it? I 've change it on size(Array)/sizoef(Array[0])

Comment: It's not "forbidden" to use `malloc` in C++, but you shouldn't do it. First of all you should be using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), and if you have to use pointers use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Smart_pointers). And if you need to allocate memory yourself explicitly then use `new[]` instead of `malloc`. Also, if you want to learn C++ properly, then please [get a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read.

Comment: ok, I will change a code, but there is so much errors

Comment: Ok, I did it , thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: It is your responsibility to know how many elements there are in an allocation. You allocated<sup>1</sup> `number` elements, so the size is `number`.

This line does not do what you think it does. It will compare the size of `int` and `int *`. On your platform they are the same size.

```
int sizeArr = sizeof(Array)/sizeof(int);
```

You are telling all your functions that you have an array of 1 element, so you sort that 1 element, and print that 1 element.

You already know how many `int`s (you are pretending) exist, it is `number`.

Rather than interpreting the result of `malloc` as a bunch of `int`s (there are no `int`s there, so your program is undefined), you can use `std::vector<int>`, which has a `size` member.

Here's a more C++ approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
std::mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()

std::vector<int> createNumbers(int number){
    std::vector<int> arr(number);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> d10(1, 10);
    std::generate_n(begin(arr), number, [&](){ return d10(gen); });
    return arr;
}

template<class FwdIt, class Compare = std::less<>>
void insertionSort(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Compare cmp = Compare{})
{
    for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
        auto const insertion = std::upper_bound(first, it, *it, cmp);
        std::rotate(insertion, it, std::next(it)); 
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    for (auto& el : vec)
    {
        os << el << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}

int main(){
    int number;
    std::cout << "Give a number of elements:";
    std::cin >> number;
    auto Numbers = createNumbers(number);
    std::cout << "Array to sort:" << Numbers;
    insertionSort(begin(Numbers), end(Numbers));
    std::cout << "Sorted array by Insertion Sort:" << Numbers;
    return 0;
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62e4127836574bd0)

1: ignoring the confusion over `int` and `int *`, which are the same size on your platform. On other platforms you have some multiple of `number` elements.

Comment: But how i should change that sizeArr?

Comment: @KasiaIks You shouldn't have `sizeArr` *at all*. A vector knows what it's size is.

Comment: And in createArray function I return this array. Does not work this way?:(

Comment: But where and how I have to use it vector?

Comment: Ok, it's too hard for me. How am I suppose to do it in C?

Comment: C and C++ are *very* different languages. Switching to C has invalidated most of my answer

Comment: Ok, I did it! <3 Thanks for your help <3